# Can we use one database for two or more application

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am about to create two applications which have the same SQLite database. I went through [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) link. But it does not make sense. I have to update the database from both applications. Please suggest one or more better ways.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about `Content Provider`

> Content providers are one of the primary building blocks of Android
>   applications, providing content to applications. They encapsulate data
>   and provide it to applications through the single ContentResolver
>   interface. A content provider is only required if you need to share
>   data between multiple applications. For example, the contacts data is
>   used by multiple applications and must be stored in a content
>   provider. If you don't need to share data amongst multiple
>   applications you can use a database directly via SQLiteDatabase.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider

Answer (score 1):

Content Provider is a great way to share database with other applications.

When you create a Content Provider, you can define which part of your database can be shared as well.

A Content Provider has following parts-
1. A class that extends ContentProvider class
2. An Authority that distinguishes this ContentProvider from others on the Android O.S.
3. A Contract class that holds Uri to tables and columns that you want to share with other applications
4. A ContentResolver to access data from a ContentProvider
5. Set of user defined permissions to write to and read from a shared  ContentProvider. Permissions allow only those apps that you authorize to access your ContentProvider

Here is a simple tutorial about the use of ContentProvider and how to share your database with other applications- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm